# Upgrading to Angular 5 NullInjectorError: No provider for

Tags: angular

Im trying to upgrade to angular 4, but when running the code I get an error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthenticatedGuard -> AuthService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthenticatedGuard -> AuthService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthService!`

The error says "No provider for AuthService", but in the very component that I'm navigating from I inject and successfully make use of my AuthService. Here are the relevant source files:

app.module.ts

```
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { AuthenticatedGuard } from '../../utility/authenticated.gaurd'
@NgModule({
    imports:[ ... ],
    declarations: [ ... ], 
    providers: [ AuthService, AuthenticatedGuard ]})
export class AppModule { }
```

authenticated.gaurd.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service.js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

        return true;
    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { AdminComponent }       from '../../components/admin/admin.component';
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin',  component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Any ideas where this error could mysteriously come from? I assume something has changes from angular 4 - 5 but I'm not sure what?

Comment: is authservice is part of shared module ???

Comment: Try changing this: `import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service.js';` to this: `import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';`. Remove the *.js* from the end.

Comment: you use 2 different simbols: `import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service'` and `import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service.js'`

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777216/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-authenticationservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service.js';
```

To this:

```
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
```

Remove the *.js* from the end of the import in the *authenticated.gaurd.ts*. The file extension is not needed for imports.

Answer (score 7):

First step:

```
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
```

Second step:

```
providers: [
    AuthService
],
```

Answer (score 1):

if you get this error then
[image]

Please add it in providers in app.module.ts

```
    providers: [
    AuthService
],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class YourService {}
```

My problem was this, I created the service without terminal shortcuts and added the injectable decorator but forgot to provide it in the root

Answer (score 0):

in your app.module.ts

```
providers: [AuthService,
    { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase},
    AuthGaurdService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Write this, works for me